# iPhone App connection between one app of ours and second whose access we dont have and is on store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to create some kind of button in the app which is already on store (Basically the shopping apps). That button should open my app with details of that shopping item searched.How to achieve this in iPhone?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to modify the behaviour of someone else's app?  That's not going to happen

Comment: No that is not the motive. I want to create something like what facebook messenger app does.The button of messenger remains on top of the screen.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The in-call bar when you are on a messenger call?  Anyway you can't get information from the other apps

Comment: Check voodoo app in android. It creates a button on top of the screen of any other shopping app (like flipkart) and gets the info of the same searched item for shopping.

Comment: Android is very different to iOS.  iOS has security and privacy foremost